# combine two queries to produce one row of results

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two queries each producing a count of records grouped by a key field

query 1

```
select link_to_contract_header, count(*) 'total1'
from calls with (nolock)
where call_type in ('HB','PI')
group by link_to_contract_header
order by link_to_contract_header
```

query 2

```
select link_to_contract_header, count(*) 'total2'
from call_events with (nolock)
inner join calls with (nolock) on link_to_call=call_ref
where call_type in ('HB','PI')
group by link_to_contract_header
order by link_to_contract_header
```

query 1 produces a result of

```
SPSL-1      1
SPTEST-1    81
SSOLUT-1    21
TEST-1      22
WARMG-1     177
```

query 2 produces a result of

```
SPSL-1      3
SPTEST-1    301
SSOLUT-1    371
TEST-1      145
WARMG-1     4339
```

so the question is.... how can i combine these two queries so that i end up with one set of results with the 2 figures in the same row?
SQL 2000 server, using SQL server management studio express 2005 to run the queries.

ie

```
SPSL-1     1   3
SPTEST-1   81  301
```

Comment: `with (nolock)` why are you doing this? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: so that we don't lock the database whilst running the queries.
it can prevent reads being deadlocked by other operations

Comment: are you able to answer the question? or are you just going to nitpick regarding the use of nolock?

Comment: If I wanted to answer your question, I would submit an answer. If you're not able to receive feedback, perhaps you shouldn't be asking questions on this community.

Comment: @chenks Pointing to a very useful resource explaining the issues that using `NOLOCK` can bring you is **not** nitpicking, it's called "trying to help other users"

Comment: i didn't ask for help on that kermit.
as i said, if you can't (or won't) answer the question then please feel free to not contribute any further

Comment: @chenks This is a website to increase and improve knowledge.  Kermit was pointing out something that might be beneficial to you or someone else which is why it was a comment and not an answer.  Don't berate him to trying to help you.

Comment: @chenks So, if you ask a question and use a code that has a dangerous vulnerability, you wouldn't want to know about it?, since you didn't ask about that?. That's not really how this community works

Comment: @Kermit some environments require the use of `nolock`, simply due to the number of transactions on a particular table. I know that general advice is to not use nolock ever, but thats not practical outside of theory. Sometimes you inherit a horribly designed DB and simply by its nature requires any investigative query against specific tables to run with `nolock`, otherwise the entire DB deadlocks and the application layer dies. While thats a good indication the stakeholders might want to implement some changes, when you are stuck managing it, you do what you have to do.

Comment: thanks Unicorno Marley for giving a sensible reply to those previous comments. and yes that is exactly the reason for using it.

Comment: @UnicornoMarley The point of my **comment** was to understand why OP was using it and if they understood the risks.

Comment: @UnicornoMarley The advice is not "don't use nolock **ever**" rather than "don't use nolock **everywhere** (at least without understanding what nolock does)"

Comment: @Kermit the point of my *comment* was to answer your question and explain why it is useful in some cases, despite the risks.

Comment: @UnicornoMarley The comment wasn't directed to you.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 it's awful practice to use `(NOLOCK)`. there are other ways to mitigate this, but `(NOLOCK)` is the laziest of them. putting that bit of helpful advice aside (thank you, @Kermit), the fact of the matter is that this question is a duplicate of any number of "join the results of subqueries" questions on here and google. it's decreasing the S/N ratio and should be treated as such.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** If you feel the need to continue this discussion, then take it to chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick way using your existing queries as derived tables

```
SELECT 
    t1.link_to_contract_header,
    t1.total1,
    t2.total2
FROM
    (select link_to_contract_header, count(*) 'total1'
    from calls with (nolock)
    where call_type in ('HB','PI')
    group by link_to_contract_header) t1
JOIN
    (select link_to_contract_header, count(*) 'total2'
    from call_events with (nolock)
    inner join calls with (nolock) on link_to_call=call_ref
    where call_type in ('HB','PI')
    group by link_to_contract_header) t2 ON t1.link_to_contract_header = t2.link_to_contract_header
```

Comment: thanks, that seems to work!
good to see some folk actually answer the question being asked.